# Replacing the value of specific field in a table-like string stored as bash variable

Tags: bash, awk

I am looking for a way to replace (with 0) a specific value (1043252782) in a "table-like" string stored as a bash variable. The output of `echo "$var"`looks like this:

```
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   090   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       1043252782
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

After the replacement `echo "$var"` should look like this:

```
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   090   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0    
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

Is there a way to do this without saving the content of `$var` to a file and directly manipulating it within the bash (shell script)?

Maby with awk? I can select the value in the 10th field of the second record with awk and pattern matching ("7 Seek_Error_Rate ....") like this:

```
echo "$var" | awk '/^  7/{print $10}'
```

Maby there is some way doing it with `awk` (or other cli-tool) to replace it and store it back into `$var`? Also, the value changes over time, but the structure remains the same (some record at the 10th field).

Comment: What's your field separator? One tab or multiple spaces?

Comment: @Cyrus it seems like the output of `smartctl -A` on a SATA hdd device. Those are spaces

Comment: @Fravadona Yes, this is an output subset from smartctl and has multiple spaces. I used it with -a Option.

Comment: Why are you getting rid of the `Seek_Error_Rate` value?

Comment: I am not getting rid of it - see my comments (below at jhnc and also your solution). However, thank you and all the others for the really fast help! I should have ask you guys earlier and saved some time :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change a specific string directly in the shell:

```
var=${var/1043252782/0}
```

To replace final number of second line, you could use awk or sed:

```
var=$(awk 'NR==2 { sub(/[0-9]+$/,0) }1' <<<"$var")
```

```
var=$(sed '2s/[0-9][0-9]*$/0/' <<<"$var")
```

If you don't know which line it will be, you can match a known string:

```
var=$(awk '/Seek_Error_Rate/{ sub(/[0-9]+$/,0) }1' <<<"$var")
```

```
var=$(sed '/Seek_Error_Rate/s/[0-9][0-9]*$/0/' <<<"$var")
```

Comment: Thanx +1. Since the the value changes over time (last sentence of my question) I do: `srch=$(echo "$var" | awk '/^  7/{print $10}')` and  then `var=${var/$srch/0}`

Comment: you can combine the search and replace since you are already using awk. An even shorter version: `var=$(echo "$var" | awk '/^  7/{sub($10,0)}1')`

Comment: Yes, this would be the perfect solution! Thanx! Only problem is that Seagate HDDs are giving constantly changing raw values for that smart attribute representing 0 error in hexadecimal. So I have to convert this number first and see if it is really 0. However, this was not part of my question. Thanx again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a here-string to feed the variable as input to `awk`.

Use `sub()` to perform a regular expression replacement.

```
var=$(awk '{sub(/1043252782$/, "0")}1' <<<"$var")
```

Comment: `var=$(awk '$NF{sub($NF "[ \t]*$", "0")}1' <<<"$var")`

Comment: I understood the question to be about replacing a specific value, not all non-zero values.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ var=$(sed '/1043252782$/s//0/' <<< "$var")
$ echo "$var"
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   090   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't wanna ruin formatting of tabs and spaces :

`{m,g}wk NF=NF FS=' 1043252782$' OFS=' 0'`
:

```
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   090   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

or doing the whole file in one single shot :

- `awk NF=NF FS=' 1043252782\n' OFS=' 0\n' RS='^$' ORS=`
- `awk NF=NF FS=' 1043252782\n' OFS=' 0\n' RS=` -- (*This might work too but I'm not too well versed in any side effects for blank `RS`*)